# Compile ptrace() program on OSX

Tags: osx, c, strace, macos, ptrace

I have this simple C program on MacOS:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("pid = %jd\n", (intmax_t) pid);
    return ptrace(PT_ATTACHEXC, pid, 0, 0);
}
```

when I compile with gcc / cc, I get this error:

> ```
> In file included from my-waiter.c:4:
> /usr/include/sys/ptrace.h:99:38: error: unknown type name 'caddr_t'
> int     ptrace(int _request, pid_t _pid, caddr_t _addr, int _data);
>                                          ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

does anyone know how to use `ptrace()` on OSX? I can't figure out how to get this to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by [user4556274](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/181036/user4556274), you need to `#include <sys/types.h>` before you `#include <sys/ptrace.h>` (see your local `ptrace(3)` manpage for details).